# SQL Server CE does not support DataReader.HasRows?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-ce

I have the following code;

```
  Dim rdr As SqlCeDataReader = cm_sel.ExecuteReader
  If rdr.HasRows Then
    While rdr.Read
      Documents.DeleteDocument(rdr.Item("fID"))
    End While
  End If
```

The error I get is:

> SQL Server Compact does not support calls to HasRows property if the
>   underlying cursor is not scrollable.

So how am I supposed to check if data exists before actually reading the DataReader?

**EDIT**

the whole code:

```
 Dim con As New SqlCeConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MyConnectionString").ToString)
 Dim cm_sel As New SqlCeCommand("SELECT fID FROM Files WHERE fCatID=" & catID, con)
   Try
     con.Open()
     Dim rdr As SqlCeDataReader = cm_sel.ExecuteReader

      If rdr.HasRows() Then
         While rdr.Read
            Documents.DeleteDocument(rdr.Item("fID"))
          End While
       End If

        Return "{'result':'ok'}"
     Catch ex As Exception
         Return "{'result':'error'}"
      Finally
          con.Close()
          con.Dispose()
      End Try
```

Comment: Seems to me like the problem is not that `HasRows` is not supported (as the title of your question implies), but rather that it is not supported in the way you are using it. Can you show the code where you set up `cm_sel`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server Compact does not support calls to HasRows property if the underlying cursor is not scrollable."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599994/sql-server-compact-does-not-support-calls-to-hasrows-property-if-the-underlying)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could call directly `reader.Read` since will return false if there are no rows. Simply remove the `if` statement surrounding the `while`.

UPDATED CODE:

```
Dim rdr As SqlCeDataReader = cm_sel.ExecuteReader
    While rdr.Read
      Documents.DeleteDocument(rdr.Item("fID"))
    End While
```

Comment: But won't alling the .Read method advance the reader one record further?

I am now editing post to reflect the whole code..

Comment: No, checkout http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read.aspx#Y456 . When you call `Read` the first time, it points to the FIRST record

Comment: I was expecting an error for non-existing records which was not thrown. But still do not get how the HasRows property cannot (not is not) be supported. I assumed the database had nothing to do with supporting this property..

Comment: Yes, it is strange indeed. You would expect that a method providing such basic data would be working without any problems :)

Comment: `while (rdr.read)` simply exits if there are 0 rows. It is quite similar to saying (pseudo) `if hasrows (read each row)`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation aaron. Now it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for the above problem.

```
 Dim hasrows As Boolean
 hasrows = False
 While (rdr.Read())
   hasrows = True
 End While
 If (hasrows) Then
  --do something
else
--do something else
end if

If you assign hasrows function to any Boolean and try to use it, the reader can jump to second record. The above solution will avoid that scenario as well.
```